# laravel api routing - how to return 404 when received unexpected url?

Tags: laravel, api, http-status-code-404

I want to resolve some problems..

in the api call,
I want to return 404 page, but it always allow any url.

For example, I intend two url what i wanted
`localhost/api/kr/[something]` and `localhost/api/en/[something]`.
but when i request like `localhost/api/dwkwdkwjdq/[someting]` it is not return 404 page..

first of all,

1. RouteServiceProvider/mapApiResource

```php
public function api(){

    $works = Work::select('some datas')
            ->where('locale', app()->getLocale())
            ->get();

    foreach ($works as $work){
        $work -> url = env('APP_URL') . '/api/' . app()->getLocale() . '/works/' . 
        $work->id;
    }

    $product_information = collect();

    $product_information->put('works', $works);

    return response()->json($product_information, 200);
}
```

2. api.php
   Route::get('/kvtext', 'Admin\AdminKvController@api');
3. Admin\AdminKvController@api
4. and app\Http\Middlewar\SetLocale.php

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next){

    $locale = $request->segment(2);

    app()->setLocale($locale);

    return $next($request);
}
```

what am I missing..?

thank you very much for reading this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a binding in your `RouteServiceProvider`'s `boot` method for allowed locales

```php
protected $locales = ['kr', ... ];

public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('locale', function ($locale) { abort_unless(in_array($locale, $this->locales), 404) });
}
```

And then you can use the `{locale}` binding on your Routes.

```php
Route::get('{locale}/something', 'Controller@action')->name('...');
```

```php
# Controller
public function action($locale)
{
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help! it works!

but is there other way with not change api.php..?

Comment: Probably, but this is the simplest way I could think of.

Comment: By the way, i really appreciate it :)